# How to include third party code in an Xcode 6 + Swift Project

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode6

I want to include some third party code (specifically https://github.com/ortuman/SwiftForms) in my XCode 6 + Swift project. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Simply add the source .swift files to your project, (**drag and drop to the file tree on the left hand side of** [Xcode - you can see the file tree here](https://camo.githubusercontent.com/0fc74c546afca078156b184c3e7d134647ac24b9/687474703a2f2f7777772e7765686561727473776966742e636f6d2f77702d636f6e74656e742f75706c6f6164732f323031342f30362f6164642d612d6e65772d7461726765742e706e67)).

The files you'll need are [here.](https://github.com/ortuman/SwiftForms/tree/master/SwiftForms/Source)

As stated on the github page: *Swift projects is currently not supported by Cocoapods. Until support is available **you should just clone the repository and drag the source folder into your project to use SwiftForms**.*

Once you have the source .swift files presenet in your Xcode project you can create a form as described in the documentation:

*"Creating a form using SwiftForms is pretty straightforward. All you need is to derive your controller from FormViewController and define a FormDescriptor instance along with its sections and rows. Here is an example of how to create a simple form to input an email and a user password."*

```
// Create form instace 
let form = FormDescriptor()
form.title = "Example form"

// Define first section
let section1 = FormSectionDescriptor()

var row: FormRowDescriptor! = FormRowDescriptor(tag: "name", rowType: .Email, title: "Email")
section1.addRow(row)

row = FormRowDescriptor(tag: "pass", rowType: .Password, title: "Password")
section1.addRow(row)

// Define second section
let section2 = FormSectionDescriptor()

row = FormRowDescriptor(tag: "button", rowType: .Button, title: "Submit")
section2.addRow(row)

form.sections = [section1, section2]

self.form = form
```

Answer (score 0):

Very easy :

1. Download the archive.
2. Extract it.
3. Move required files to your project folder
4. Add the required files to your project.
5. Clean project

It's done

Comment: Note also that [Cocoapods](http://cocoapods.org) will support Swift projects in a near future.